# Writing Special Chars in Xml Tag ( Google Product Xml Feed )

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, google-product-search

I'm working on google product feed xml with C#

I can generate a xml with using XmlSerializer but I can't solve just one problem;

In xml feed example, product id has to be like this;

```
    ...
    <item>
        <title>Super item</title>
        <link>http://www.bla.com/13007/2202170/</link>
        <description>Test description</description>
        <g:id>1234678</g:id>
    </item>
    ...
```

But as you can see special " : " char in xml element tag.

So when I write "[XmlElement("g:id")]" on my property like;

```
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("g:id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

XmlSerializer generetad my xml tag like; < g_X003A_id >
And generated xml looking like this;

```
...
<item>
    <title>Super item</title>
    <link>http://www.bla.com/13007/2202170/</link>
    <description>Test description</description>
    <g_X003A_id>1234678</g_X003A_id>
</item>
...
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The "g:" is a namespace prefix. Read about XML namespaces.

Comment: I tried several combinations like "[XmlElement(Namespace = "g", DataType = null, ElementName = "id" )]" but no luck. How I solve this problem with class/property tagging? I can write my serializer like this one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024482/building-a-google-product-feed-in-net-c But I don't want to change my solution with writing my project again...

Comment: g: is a *prefix*. The namespace will be a URI. Look for xmlns:g="http://something" in the original file.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/945246/1402923). It should clear up how to add namespaces to Xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem like;

```
        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement("id", Namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")] //g:id
        public int Id { get; set; }
```